# Simplest way to query a elasticsearch index with chained conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of products on which I want to find all the products who fulfill conditions , such as :

((type = "orange" and price > 10) or (type = "apple" and price > 8)) and on_sale=True.

What about

(type = "orange" or type = "apple") and (price <= 25 or on_sale=True) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine bool clauss, with "must" and "should".
Find below the required query for the first statement

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "on_sale": {
              "value": "True"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "orange"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "price": {
                          "gte": 10
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": {
                          "value": "apple"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "price": {
                          "gte": 8
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is just about wrapping "must" or "Should" clauses into one another as required. You need a little bit of practise to figure out how to chain them. But literally any combination can be queried using this kind of syntax.

For the second query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "type": [
              "ornage",
              "apple"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "on_sale": {
                    "value": "True"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "price": {
                    "gte": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When you need "and" use "MUST", when you need "or" use "SHOULD".

HTH.